# How to Link Models in Django? ForiegnKey vs Parent Linking

Tags: django, django-models

I want to link `stdClass` and `stdDetails` with `schoolDetails` in such a way that I can access `stdClass` and `stdDetails` via `schoolDetails` without rendering the whole models in the WebPage. Is foreign key best to do it?

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class schoolDetails(models.Model):
    sname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    subdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Nepal')
    estdate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    numstd = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200, default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=95)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sname


class stdClass(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    ssname = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    cList = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.cList
class stdDetails(models.Model):
    ondelete = models.ForeignKey(schoolDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    stname = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    ssname = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    stadd = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    stcls = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    stfname = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    stmname = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    stfo = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    stadate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    stpnum = models.CharField(max_length=95, null=True)
    stbdate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    stpht = models.ImageField(max_length=500, upload_to='')
    #(""), upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None,
    def __str__(self):
        return self.stname
#datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 25, 2, 33, 57, 858649, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Comment: You should have relation with one another in any way. In `stdClass`, it seems to be independent table. Like this: **You can't**.

Comment: Can't get you bro?